# Extract text address within Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

```html
<tr class="prem-tr" id="10425" role="row">
                    <td>
                        <h4><a class="prem-result-link" href="/Search/Details/10425">Graham &amp; Associates, CPAs</a></h4>

                        <a href="tel:+(205) 663-6673">(205) 663-6673</a>
                        <br>

                        5 Brown Circle<br>

                        Alabaster,

                        AL &nbsp;&nbsp;

                        35007

                        <div class="row result-btmRow">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <span class="result-dist"><small>Distance: 0.00 miles</small></span>
                            </div><!-- col6 -->
                            <div class="col-sm-8 result-actions">
                                <a id="WebsiteURL" class="visit-site" href="http://grahamandassociates.net" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                <a class="send-email" href="/Search/Details/10425">Send a Message</a>
                            </div><!-- /col6 -->
                        </div><!-- /row -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

How to extract the Address using `CSS` selector within Scrapy?

Expected output:

```
5 Brown Circle, Alabaster, AL 35007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
res = " ".join([" ".join(el.root.strip().split()) for el in your_scrapy_block.css("td::text") if el.root.strip()])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
5 Brown Circle Alabaster, AL 35007
```